# Assigning Numeric Value to Letters, Tallying with Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created a table that was not the most intuitive- but it essentially has one long row of tallies, and a graded score. 
I essentially wanted to convert the tallies into points, dependent on the grade I had given them. For instance, 2 tallies with the grade "B" would equal to 1 point.

Afterwards I wanted to sum the total value of all points for the individual "Bob"

Would this be possible with a pivot table? I have absolutely no idea how to approach this... Any help would be appreciated!

**Sample image below:**

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: May I have a look at the source data, the one that you used to build the table that has long row of tallies? I guess you can restructure your pivot table or use some other formulas to find out the score for each person without needing to create a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach your requirements, if you can create new column with formula to calculate the points.

If I assume the following, I can create a formula:
- The table is 3 columns x 1 Row, Tally = Bob, Grade1 = 2A, Grade2 = 1B
- Grades will always be 2 digits, like 2A and 1B

The formula could be :

=left(Grade1,1) x if(right(Grade1,1)="A",1, if(right(Grade1,1)="B",0.5))

+left(Grade2,1) x if(right(Grade2,1)="A",1, if(right(Grade2,1)="B",0.5))

Comment: Would that be adding a new column after every "Grade" ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new column, you can just take advantage of the vlookup function:

```
=B7*LEFT(VLOOKUP(E7,A2:B3,2,FALSE),LEN(VLOOKUP(E7,A2:B3,2,FALSE))-6)+ 
 D7*LEFT(VLOOKUP(E7,A2:B3,2,FALSE),LEN(VLOOKUP(E7,A2:B3,2,FALSE))-6)
```

Where:

B7 is the value of first tally

C7 is the value of first grade

a2:b3 keeps the grading scheme

d7 is the value of first tally

e7 is the value of first grade